# Use a specific database and table in MSSQL (Visual Studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, database-server

I am working in Visual Studio and using the SQL manager built into the studio. Now I am connecting to several databases and I would very much like to be able to save and open my SQL queries and still have them access the correct database and table.

So:

```
Database servers:
db.company.com
    databasenumber1
    databasenumber2
    databasenumber3
db2.company.com
    databasenumber1
    databasenumber2
    databasenumber3
db3.company.com
    databasenumber1
    databasenumber2
    databasenumber3
```

Now I wish to write an sql query that does something simple, lets say:

```
select * from users where userid = '12';
```

However I want to select this from `database server db2` and from `database databasenumber3`.

How do I write that in a `use` statement? Or is there something other than "use"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working among several databases in once script file requires USE  followed by GO statement.

```
USE db1;
GO

SQL statements ...
...


USE db2;
GO

SQL statements ...
...
```

Another option is to use `server.dbname.tablename` format but that strictly requires that all of your databases are hosted on same server.

```
SELECT * FROM server.db1.table1  
SELECT * FROM server.db2.table2
...
```

Comment: I don't get this to work.

db1.company.com is one computer which has a database engine running on it. db2.company.com is a completely different computer with a database engine running on that, even on a different subnet.

Under SQL Servers in Visual Studio I have them connected, can browse them and work with them (in the SQL Server Object Explorer).

If I write "use db1; go" I get this error:
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Database 'db1' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

(Sorry for lousy formatting. I don't understand the formatting guide)